# trying to use select in dplyr in a more compact way

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to use dplyr and the %>% symbol with multiple selection. 
What works:

```
   select(data, b1:b10) / select(data, v1:v10)
```

What I would like to do:

```
data %>% select(b1:b10)/select(v1:v10)
```

Comment: So the `:` selects on the basis of column order in the `data`, not on the basis of pattern matching? Seems like a potential for including variables you didn't mean to.

Comment: `b1:b10` selects all columns from `b1` to `b10`

Comment: @Alex - Considering selecting by column name is possible in R, positional selection seems pretty clumsy for the current task. What if someone/something moves or adds a column?

Comment: Creeping [SPSS dataset logic](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/spss/faq/to.htm) into R seems like a definite 'badness'(tm).

Comment: @thelatemail  SAS has a similar selection syntax. It can be very convenient when you have well-defined input files (which ideally should be *always*). Making certain tasks easier always seems to come at the cost of more risk/assumptions.

Comment: @MrFlick - anything that both SAS and SPSS agree on is not strengthening its argument for inclusion in my mind :-)

Comment: @thelatemail Fair point. :) I just wanted to side with him that it's not a ridiculous request.

Comment: @thelatemail, how is this behavior any different from the behavior of "select" in `subset`? I guess I'm just saying that I'm not too surprised by this.

Comment: @AnandaMahto - I don't think `subset` has any way of specifying `var1:var3` that might problematically capture `var1/newvar/var2/var3` in one go. Happy to be proven wrong.

Comment: @MrFlick - the OP's question is not ridiculous at all. The fundamental way that `:` is operating in this context just seems risky to me.

Comment: @thelatemail, what do you get with `mydf <- data.frame(var1 = 1, newvar = 2, var2 = 3, var4 = 4); subset(mydf, select = var1:var2)`?

Comment: @AnandaMahto - I stand corrected. I do however stand by not liking the way that works. I pretty much never use `subset` so I wasn't familiar with the `select=` variations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
#sample data
data<-data.frame(matrix(runif(20*45), ncol=20, 
    dimnames=list(NULL, paste0(rep(c("b","v"), each=10),1:10))) )

#orig
A<-select(data, b1:b10) / select(data, v1:v10)

#proposed
B<-data %>% function(X) {select(X, b1:b10)/select(X, v1:v10)}

#verify they are the same
all(A==B)
```

I also have a helper function called [withX](https://gist.github.com/MrFlick/35ff2265619762d49159#file-withx-r) that i use a lot in situations like this

```
C <- data %>% withX( select(X, b1:b10) / select(X, v1:v10) )
all(C==A)
# [1] TRUE
```

Or maybe in this case we might like another helper function for working the the chain and creating a list form different subsets. Consider the function `each`

```
each<-function(.data, ...) {
    dots <- substitute(list(...))[-1]
    force(.data)
    e<-environment()
    parent.env(e)<-parent.frame()
    lapply(dots, function(x) {
        eval(bquote(.data %>% .(x)), e)
    })
}
```

This function will perform the `dplyr` chaining for each parameter you pass in. So you can do

```
D <- data %>% each(select(b1:b10), select(v1:v10)) %>% Reduce(`/`, .)
all(A==D)
# [1] TRUE
```

Now I realize all these alternative methods aren't "compact" in the sense of fewer characters. But you do only have to specify the data.frame name once. So there's that.

Comment: Thanks for all the alternatives! I'll try them all.